# How to change user account picture

Tags: windows-server-2012

Is it possible to change your user account picture in Windows Server 2012?

Comment: Typically those settings can be found in Control Panel\Users and edit specific user

Comment: Not in Server 2012...

Answer (score 5):

In Server 2012, similar to Server 2008 R2; the 'Desktop Experience' feature is required to achieve the similar interface experience as Win7/8.  This feature can be added from the Server Manager, under 'User Interfaces and Infrastructure.'  Once added, either Win+I to Change PC Settings/Personalize/Account Picture, or from the Metro Start screen, click the username charm in the upper right corner, select change account picture.

Cheers~