# How do I set photo of my users?

Tags: windows-server-2012, microsoft-office-2013

I see that Windows 8/Windows Server 2012 RDS user login photo, and when recieving mails there's a "template" photo of the user sending the mail...

[image]

Can I globally set photo of all my users, so they show in logon screen (no matter what pc they log into), everyones mails etc? Or do each user have to assign a photo to a contact person (even though this contact person is in the coporate)?

Hope you get what I mean. :)

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change user account picture](http://superuser.com/questions/492478/how-to-change-user-account-picture)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Exchange server, you can (and I believe must) set the `thumbnailPhoto` Active Directory property with a binary image. This can be accomplished programmatically in Powershell -- one (of many) tutorials can be found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/03/10/3409495.aspx. It can also be accomplished in C# through `System.DirectoryServices`.

Answer (score 1):

In Server 2012/2012R2, Desktop Experience feature must be installed to use user pictures, even for Active Directory User Pictures.

There are free tools to set Active Directory users Pictures, for example http://www.codetwo.com/freeware/active-directory-photos/